# Scroll View in RadCartesian Bar Chart

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing iOS and Android mobile applications using native script angular. I am using a bar chart to display monthly yearly reports in the radcartesian plugin. In the bar chart, I want the horizontal scroll to show the large records. Is it possible to use a horizontal scroll view inside the bar chart in the radcartesian chart?

Comment: I'm not sure about the ability to scroll. But you may set allowZoom / allowPan to true on the axis which would allow user to zoom and move across the access. For more clarity you may raise an issue at [UI feedback repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues)

Comment: I expand (zoom in) the graph and I put another set of graph values app crashed in Ios. I thought to zoom out the graph before putting the graph values. Are you know how to zoom out the graph programmatically.

Comment: It must be possible, but doesn't look like such API is exposed. Also as I mentioned it's not open source hence it's hard to go through the code to find how, it's better to raise an issue.